# In ASP MVC3, how can execute a controller and action using a uri?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

How can I, when executing a controller action, take a Uri (not the one requested) and invoke the action from the controller that would have been executed had that Uri been the one that was called? I can't simply redirect to that action as I need it to happen in the same request context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the HttpContext (and I suppose you do since you are asking) you could:

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
// controller and action are compulsory
routeData.Values["action"] = "index";
routeData.Values["controller"] = "foo";
// some additional route parameter
routeData.Values["foo"] = "bar";
IController fooController = new FooController();
var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext), routeData);
fooController.Execute(rc);
```

Personally I use this approach for handling errors inside my application. I put this in `Application_Error` and execute an error controller for custom error pages staying in the context of the initial HTTP request. You could also place complex objects inside the `routeData` hash and you will get those complex objects back as action parameters. I use this to pass the actual exception that occurred to the error controller action.

---

UPDATE:

In order to parse an URL to its route data tokens taking into account current routes you could:

```
var request = new HttpRequest(null, "http://foo.com/Home/Index", "id=1");
var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
var values = routeData.Values;
var action = values["action"];
var controller = values["controller"];
```

Comment: This is like what I am planning, but I don't have the action/controller - all I have is the uri

Comment: @mcintyre321, please see my update for parsing an URL to its constituent route data tokens.

Comment: Can's we use like this `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));` ? Isn't it recommended ?

Comment: @ihihjkjk, no because that would tie the code to an ASP.NET context making it impossible to be unit tested in isolation.

Comment: Want to add a point. In MVC, unit test project, in case I am directly using the `HttpContext`, it will always be null. On the other hand we can create a object of `httpcontextwrapper` based upon instance of httpcontext by passing the `httprequest` and `httpresponse` information

Answer (score 2):

For the correct answer, I'd prefer do something like this to let MVC handle creating controllers rather than creating myself.

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
// controller and action are compulsory
routeData.Values["action"] = "index";
routeData.Values["controller"] = "foo";
IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(yourHttpContextObject), routeData);
var controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, "FooController");
try
{
   controller.Execute(requestContext);
}
finally
{
   factory.ReleaseController(controller);
}
```

This would assure you that your Foo controller is getting the same behavior as other controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't push the code you are calling into a controller-independent class? Cross-calling controllers sounds like a bit of a WTF to me.

Comment: I'm going to push it into a TransferResult(Uri uriToTransferTo)