# Capture the result of an Action by executing a Controller programatically (using RouteData)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I found the following answer from Darin Dimitrov - [In ASP MVC3, how can execute a controller and action using a uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5213320/647845)

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
// controller and action are compulsory
routeData.Values["action"] = "index";
routeData.Values["controller"] = "foo";
// some additional route parameter
routeData.Values["foo"] = "bar";
IController fooController = new FooController();
var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext), routeData);
fooController.Execute(rc);
```

The only problem is that I like to capture the ViewResult that is returned by this Action (to render it as a string), but IController.Execute returns `void`.

I suspect I can find the Result somewhere in the property of the ControllerContext, but I can't find anything like that. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: the link you provided also makes use of the HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, as far as I understand is to actually render the view, get the HTML result and assert against it.

This is practically testing the view which is pretty much not recommended and against most practices.

However, you could come up with some solutions to this. The one presented (simplified and a bit messy) is using RazorEngine to render the view. Since you can't get access to the .cshtml (the view file) from the test project you will need to get to its contents in a messy way.

Install RazorEngine NuGet package to your test project and try something along these lines:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var x = new HomeController();  // instantiate controller
        var viewResult = (ViewResult)x.Index(); // run the action and obtain its ViewResult
        var view = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewResult.ViewName) ? "Index" : viewResult.ViewName;     // get the resulted view name; if it's null or empty it means it is the same name as the action
        var controllerName = "Home"; // the controller name was known from the beginning

        // actually navigate to the folder containing the views; in this case we're presuming the test project is a sibling to the MVC project, otherwise adjust the path to the view accordingly
        var pathToView = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");
        pathToView = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToView);
        pathToView = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToView);
        pathToView = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToView);
        pathToView = Path.Combine(pathToView, "WebApplication5\\Views\\" + controllerName + "\\" + view + ".cshtml");

        var html = Razor.Parse(File.ReadAllText(pathToView), viewResult.Model);  // this is the HTML result, assert against it (i.e. search for substrings etc.)
    }
```